# Redis stream XReadGroup not reading new messages even if `BLOCK` parameter is 0

Tags: redis, go-redis

I am using redis stream and `XReadGroup` for reading messages from stream. I have set `block` parameter as 0.
currently my code look like this

```
data, err := w.rdb.XReadGroup(ctx, &redis.XReadGroupArgs{
            Group:    w.opts.group,
            Consumer: w.opts.consumer,
            Streams:  []string{w.opts.streamName, ">"},
            Count: 1,
            Block: 0,
        }).Result()
```

I am currently facing a problem that if I keep the application (involving this code) idle for 10-12 hours, XReadGroup is not able to read new messages, if I restart the application then all the new messages consumed at once. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a block time of let's say 10s, it does not change anything (I guess the code you provided is in a `while(true)`).

From my experience you can keep the app idle for days and it still works.

I don't really know why but I guess it has to do with the "constant" back and forth "reseting" the connection.

Comment: Its fixed now. The problem was that whenever there was err from XReadGroup due to connection break the while(true) loop was breaking. I avoided that. Also I added block time of 1 minute.

Comment: can you give more info on the xreadgroup parameters you pass ?

Comment: @Jefry90 I guess you can find what you want here : https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup/

Comment: thank you , fixed in with adding BLOCK param to the xreadgroup